# HTML file on Windows desktop

Tags: windows, html, file-shortcut

I no longer have a Windows machine to work with.

If I make an HTML file containing links a friend wants, and he puts it on his Windows 10 desktop, what I think should happen is the same thing that happens on Mac, i.e., double-clicking the file icon launches the default browser with the HTML rendered the same as if it were on a web server instead.

But I vaguely remember before retirement having to do more complicated things to build a Windows shortcut.

Is my "what I think" correct, or do I have to do more?  If so, is there a way to do it on a Mac/Linux?  (I am capable of editing any text or binary.)

Comment: Hello, What do you mean by "to build a Windows shortcut" when you are talking about HTML? If you want to have some links to display in an html to some site, just make a body container and put there the links. It should work on windows.

Comment: I'll send it and see whether he can use i.  He's extremely non-technical.  When I was in I.T., there were a few times I had to "open" a shortcut and change different parameters to make it work.  I gave him the links in a page on a web site, but he has to get to the site to use them.  So I want to just give him a local file that he can click on.

Comment: This is handled by file extension association

Answer (score 0):

If you make a HTML file, regardless of Operating System, every other Operating System can open it as HTML is a global language.

The file will open on their default web browser and they will see the links as you have displayed them in your HTML file.

Nothing additional should need to be done at all.

(Tl;dr - HTML format won’t change if it is just HTML Links within a body tag. This should be fine for anyone to open and click the links.)